# android webview load large js not effect

Tags: android

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:LanxinJSBridge._dispatchMessageFromNative('{\"responseData\":\"\",\"responseId\":\"cb_1_1451095189789\",\"status\":\"success\"}');");
```

I use it to call js method with a json string param.It's ok.
However when the params is very large , the string is about 2600 length , then the js method will not be called , why?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have  **JavaScript** enabled on your webview component?

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```